# Is there a way to dynamically insert / Add UI in a fluidRow in a Shiny app

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app that allows me dynamically add UI control widget. However, the current code would add a new row for each new UI widget. Is there a way to add them into a fluidRow, so that each row would take up to 4 widgets.

Also, is there a way to add/remove control widgets without defaulting all the current selections? The code I have right now basically regenerate the control widgets everything time "Add" or "Remove" button is hit, which means all the selection will reset to default.

Thank you a lot for your help. 
The code is as following.

Thank you!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(


  mainPanel(
    actionButton("add_btn", "Add Box"),
    actionButton("rm_btn", "Remove Box"),
    uiOutput("interactionUI"))

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # Track the number of input boxes to render
  counter <- reactiveValues(n = 0)

  observeEvent(input$add_btn, {counter$n <- counter$n + 1})
  observeEvent(input$rm_btn, {
    if (counter$n > 0) counter$n <- counter$n - 1
  })


  interaction <- reactive({

    n <- counter$n

    if (n > 0) {
      lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) {
        selectInput(inputId = paste0("item", i),
                    label = paste0("Item", i), choices=c("test","test2"),
                    selected = NULL,
                    multiple = 8, selectize = TRUE, width = "20%", size = NULL)
      })
    }

  })

  output$interactionUI <- renderUI({ interaction() })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Look at the demo of insertUI/removeUI https://gallery.shinyapps.io/111-insert-ui/

Comment: Hi Geovany, Thank you for the note. My question is that is there a way to put these inserted UI in a fluidRow. so that when you add new UI items, it will add in the horizontal direction, instead of stacking all the new UI in the vertical direction.

Answer (score 2):

Add an id tagged div inside of a fluid row then reference this id as the selector to insert a column.

```
fluidRow(tags$div(id="rowLabel",column(4,"Example1",textOutput("example1"))))

insertUI(selector = "#rowLabel",where = "afterEnd",ui = tags$div(id="columnLabel",column(4,"Example2",textOutput("example2"))))
```

I add the div id wrapper to the inserted column to make it easy to delete later.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is an old question, but I just had the same problem and thought it would be nice to share my solution for it. 
I took inspiration from: https://www.r-bloggers.com/dynamic-ui-elements-in-shiny/

Basically, you should store the UI elements from the lapply call in a variable, and then use a do.call() with your preferred Shiny layout (in my case, flowLayout generated a better result than fluidRow).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(


  mainPanel(
    actionButton("add_btn", "Add Box"),
    actionButton("rm_btn", "Remove Box"),
    uiOutput("interactionUI"))

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # Track the number of input boxes to render
  counter <- reactiveValues(n = 0)

  observeEvent(input$add_btn, {counter$n <- counter$n + 1})
  observeEvent(input$rm_btn, {
    if (counter$n > 0) counter$n <- counter$n - 1
  })


  output$interactionUI <- renderUI({

    n <- counter$n

    if (n > 0) {
      interaction <- lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) {
        selectInput(inputId = paste0("item", i),
                    label = paste0("Item", i), choices=c("test","test2"),
                    selected = NULL,
                    multiple = 8, selectize = TRUE, width = "20%", size = NULL)
      })
    }
    do.call(flowLayout, interaction)

  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```